# git: "bad line length character: Shel" when pushing rep to ftp

Tags: git, ftp

I type

```
git push --set-upstream ssh://antyusos@ftp.anty-usos.host-ed.me/projekt.git master
```

cmd returns:

> antyusos@ftp.anty-usos.host-ed.me's password: [here I type correct password]
>   fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Shel

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't you confusing `SSH` with `FTP`? Git does not support pushes via `FTP` -- currently supported transports include `SSH` and `HTTP[S]` ("smart" and "dumb" versions). `rsync` transport might work but is obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Godaddy hosting for example, this error could occur **because your SSH access is disabled**.

So the server just closes the connection immediately and GIT show us

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Shel.
```

Which means Shell access is denied/closed/etc i think.

Go to your cPanel and enable it. `cPanel -> Settings -> SSH Access.`

This can occur even if you have already enabled it before. They switch it off periodically.

**If it's already enabled** though, just disable and re-enable it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when I was trying to reach a repo in an Apache user's directory. [In my server (CentOS 6.4), users are being created through CPanel component.]

What this error possibly means is that the user you are using doesn't have shell access, only web and FTP or other protocols.

If you have access to your web server, I will tell you how to solve it, but make sure if you can't solve it by adding a new user since apache users are the users that executes web pages, using them for shell access might cause security problems.

Open `passwd` in your editor:

```
vim /etc/passwd
```

Find the line that contains your user's configuration and check the last path. It should be like this:

```
antyusos:x:306:307:/home/antyusos:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
```

What matters here is the last path, "/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell". Change this line to:

```
antyusos:x:306:307:/home/antyusos:/bin/bash
```

Save & exit the editor.

Hopefully, it should work. At least it did for me. But as I said, I find it dangerous and as the last option.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in [this thread](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/node/303), make sure that:

- there isn't already an active ssh session
- the `.bashrc` or `.profile` of `antyusos` user account isn't echoing some message which would then be incorrectly interpreted by git on your server.

Comment: I've removed all content of those files and disconnected from FTP in Total Commander but still no luck.

Comment: @OverdrivenFall what does a `ssh ssh://antyusos@ftp.anty-usos.host-ed.me` returns?

Comment: `C:\[...]>git push --set-upstream ssh ssh://antyusos@ftp.anty-u1sos.host-ed.me` returns:     
`fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in ssh://antyusos@ftp.anty-usos.host-ed.me`

Comment: @OverdrivenFall my question was about executing `ssh ssh://antyusos@ftp.anty-usos.host-ed.me`, not using that as part of `git push` (which would not work, as you saw)

Comment: oh, then it returns:
`'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: **Shel**

I was using a godaddy account, and **Shel** was the *beginning* of the ssh connecting error message:

> **Shel**l not enabled for this account.

I opened a customer service window, the turned shell **off** then back **on** again, and now it works again.